# Hopper pull less then 5 items at once

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How can I pull a certain amount of items from a chest using hopper. The chest is full of unstackable items such as tools and armor. How can I get the first 4 items? For 5, I can use the hopper until it gets full.

Comment: Do you want to pull 4 items at a time, or only pull exactly 4 items?

Comment: 4 items at time

Comment: Could you expand on what you are trying to accomplish in that case?  There's no way to fit four hoppers under one chest, but if you need something to move items quickly you can use multiple hoppers and chests to "multi-thread" it.

Comment: I want to make a "card" game that requires to draw "cards" that are unstackable items (tools...) . Also I want to be able to draw 1,2,3,4 and 5 "cards" at a time from chest and give those drawn items to player to player

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution for this is a comparator which leads to a circuit that turns off the hopper once it hits four items, using have a redstone wire that wraps around with exactly as many blocks as the comparator will power when there are four items, ending with powering the hopper (which makes it stop taking more items).  With a somewhat more modular design you could even set it up to stop the hopper at any number of items, using the same power distance property of the comparator.